# Laravel send mail returns success but no mail gets to the client. When using Mailtrap, the mail is delivered

Tags: laravel

Am having a Laravel project in which I want to send direct emails from. Upon sending, Laravel replies with a success message but from the email's inbox, I got no email. When using Mailtrap, everything is working fine but this happens on production.

Comment: Did you check the spam folder ?

Comment: Yeah but there is none.